# Javascript function always return undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have this vue2 code:

```
checkUser2() {
    var returnValue;
    axios.get(`api/users/CheckUsername/${this.username}`)
          .then(response => {
              returnValue = response.data.error === 0;
          }, errorCallBack => {
              returnValue = false;
          });
    return returnValue;
}
```

I call it with:

```
var a = this.checkUser2();
console.log(a);
```

and it always returns undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because the ajax call is asynchronous. It finishes *after* the function has returned.

Comment: The returnValue will only be filled once the ajax call is complete. So if you write the console.log inside the success callback then, it will be printed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to return the value from this method, then you will have to return the *promise* from the function and use a callback to capture the result on success.

```
checkUser2() {
    return axios.get(`api/users/CheckUsername/${this.username}`)
      .then(response => response.data.error === 0, errorCallBack => false);
}
```

And when you call it:

```
this.checkUser2().then(value => console.log(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about vue2, but I do know that `axios` works on promises, so since you are returning `returnValue` outside of your promise, your function is returning the current value of `returnValue`, which is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are returning the value before the request was made. You need to make a Promise, and when it resolves, return the value.

```
checkUser2() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var returnValue;
    axios.get(`api/users/CheckUsername/${this.username}`)
    .then(response => {
      returnValue = response.data.error === 0;
      resolve(returnValue);
    }, errorCallBack => {
      returnValue = false;
      reject(returnValue);
    });
  });
}
```

Then you just need to call it like this to get the value:

```
this.checkUser2().then(val => {
 a = val;
})
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: axios.get returns a promise.